# Store histogram value in array to compare with input image - android opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm doing a project using `opencv` in `android studio`.

My project is about comparing colour histogram of an input image captured by camera with the 6 images that is stored in the drawable. The `opencv` function that I used is `comparHist()`. The purpose of the comparison is to know if the input image has matched colour to any images in the drawable.

My problem is I need to calculate colour histogram using `calcHist()` for every 6 images every time there is an input image(captured by camera) so that I can compare them. I was thinking to store the colour histogram value of 6 images in an array. Can I do so?

I was searching for a solution but there is none. Here is my code that I have done.

public int resultRecog() {
drawImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.onefront);

```
    Mat hsv_base = new Mat();
    Mat hsv_test = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(drawImg, hsv_base);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(pic, hsv_test);

    /// Convert to HSV
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv_base, hsv_base, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv_test, hsv_test, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    /// h s bins value
    MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(40, 40);

    //// ranges h=0-180, s=0-256
    MatOfFloat ranges = new MatOfFloat(0f, 180f, 0f, 256f);

    /// two channel
    MatOfInt channels = new MatOfInt(0, 1);

    Mat hist_base = new Mat();
    Mat hist_test = new Mat();

    ArrayList<Mat> histImages = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    histImages.add(hsv_base);
    Imgproc.calcHist(histImages, channels, new Mat(), hist_base, histSize, ranges, false);
    Core.normalize(hist_base, hist_base, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    histImages = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    histImages.add(hsv_test);
    Imgproc.calcHist(histImages, channels, new Mat(), hist_test, histSize, ranges, false);
    Core.normalize(hist_test, hist_test, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    double result = Imgproc.compareHist(hist_base, hist_test, 0);

    drawImg.recycle();
    drawImg = null;

    int r;

    if (result >= 0.15) {
        r = 1;
    } else {
        drawImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fivefront);
        Mat hsv_base5 = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(drawImg, hsv_base5);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv_base5, hsv_base5, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        Mat hist_base5 = new Mat();

        ArrayList<Mat> histImages5 = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        histImages5.add(hsv_base5);
        Imgproc.calcHist(histImages5, channels, new Mat(), hist_base5, histSize, ranges, false);
        Core.normalize(hist_base5, hist_base5, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        result = Imgproc.compareHist(hist_base5, hist_test, 0);

        drawImg.recycle();
        drawImg = null;

        if (result >= 0.1) {
            r = 5;
        } else {
            drawImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f10);

            Mat hsv_base10 = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(drawImg, hsv_base10);

            Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv_base10, hsv_base10, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

            Mat hist_base10 = new Mat();

            ArrayList<Mat> histImages10 = new ArrayList<Mat>();
            histImages10.add(hsv_base10);
            Imgproc.calcHist(histImages10, channels, new Mat(), hist_base10, histSize, ranges, false);
            Core.normalize(hist_base10, hist_base10, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

            result = Imgproc.compareHist(hist_base10, hist_test, 0);

            drawImg.recycle();
            drawImg = null;

            if (result >= 0.1) {
                r = 10;
            } else {

                    drawImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fiftyfront);
                    Mat hsv_base50 = new Mat();
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(drawImg, hsv_base50);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv_base50, hsv_base50, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

                    Mat hist_base50 = new Mat();

                    ArrayList<Mat> histImages50 = new ArrayList<Mat>();
                    histImages50.add(hsv_base50);
                    Imgproc.calcHist(histImages50, channels, new Mat(), hist_base50, histSize, ranges, false);
                    Core.normalize(hist_base50, hist_base50, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

                    result = Imgproc.compareHist(hist_base50, hist_test, 0);

                    drawImg.recycle();
                    drawImg = null;

                    if (result >= 0.1) {
                        r = 50;
                    } else {
                            r = 0;
                        }
            }//rm10
        }//rm5
    }//rm1
        return r;
    }
```

So my question is, can I store the colour histogram value (of 6 images stored in the drawable) in an array so that the application doesn't need to re-calculate the colour histogram every time there is input image captured by camera